# Check if record exists in Rails before creating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to search my database before I enter the record, by doing this:

```
Product.update_or_create_by_name_and_date_and_applicationURL_and_server_and_addi_servers(app_name, app_date,url_app,server_name,addi_servers)
```

the problem is that I get an undefined method exception!

Is there another way to search for the same record before entering one?

Comment: AFAIC referencing dynamic methods like that one is an abuse of anyone that ever has to read your code. If this is a common operation, create a scope that's contextually meaningful to *your* app, and make it explicit.

Answer (score 2):

You should use two steps:

```
#Suggestion 1
obj = Product.find_or_create_by_...


#Suggestion 2
obj = Product.find_or_initialize_by_...

obj.update_attributes hash_here
```

Rereading, your question, I can't really understand what do you want to update if you try to find an object with known attributes. Anyway, you would just have to adapt my answer a little if some fields are for identifying and some for update.

Comment: really depends on your need, I commented my answer since it's not very clear to me

Comment: Rails 3.2 introduced first_or_create, first_or_create!, first_or_initialize. Changelog says: *This is a better approach over the old find_or_create_by dynamic methods because it's clearer which arguments are used to find the record and which are used to create it: **User.where(:first_name => "Scarlett").first_or_create!(:last_name => "Johansson")***

Answer (score 0):

I would define a function in your model: something like

```
Product.find_by_everything
```

where you write out all the parameters of the search, instead of using the the long naming method.

Then, if that returns nil, create the product. This doesn't seem to be a good use case of using the built in activerecord naming methods.